# Using .remove on a table row produces style of display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a row from my table.  Each row contains a text input, edit button and delete button.  When I click delete I want the entire row to be removed.  This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#delete_x',  function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
    });
});
```

I don't have access to the rows id's so am getting the closest tr to the delete button.  My problem is instead of removing the row, a new inline style of display:none appears in my tr!  I am wondering why this is happening? I am using safari browser on a mac yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to remove a row which is parent of the row animated instead of the row itself.

This is because actual "this" value depends on the call site or if, like in most of jquery methods, to something explicitly forced.

In jquery "this" is usually forced to be the element you are acting on. So when you pass a callback to the fadeOut() method, inside this callback, "this" will point to the element that is faded out (in this case the row you want to remove).

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#delete_x',  function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

...or even clearer:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#delete_x',  function () {
    var me = $(this).closest('tr');
    me.fadeOut(500, function(){
        me.remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fadeOut() is not the same as deleting a row. You want .remove()

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly after I changed it to .remove()!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). You want simple to remove the element using jquery [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#delete_x', function () {
    $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();
});
```

p.s. I want to see also a copy of yout html mark up.